# Quick sort algorithm giving wrong outputs on last two elements

Tags: algorithm, sorting, quicksort

```
def swap(a, p, q):
    # print('p is: ', p)
    tmp = a[p]
    a[p] = a[q]
    a[q] = tmp
    return a


def partition(a, q):
    # if flag == 0:
    # q is the POSITION of pivot not pivot
    print('q is: ', q)
    r = len(a) - 1
    print('heyyyyyyy', a, q)
    p = a[q]
    i = q + 1
    comparison = 0
    for j in range(q + 1, r):
        print('my name is j:', j)
        comparison += 1
        if a[j] < p:
            print('j is:', j)
            a = swap(a, i, j)
            i += 1
    a = swap(a, q, i - 1)
    return a, i - 1, comparison


def choosePivot(a, flag):
    if flag == 0:
        return 0


def QuickSort(a, flag):
    # pivot = a[0]
    # base case
    if len(a) < 2:
        return a, 0
    else:
        p = choosePivot(a, 0)
        print('pivot is hhhhh: ', a, p)
        a, newPivotPos, comparisons = partition(a, p)
        print(a, newPivotPos, comparisons)
        A = a[0:newPivotPos]
        B = a[newPivotPos + 1:]
        a[0:newPivotPos], left = QuickSort(A, flag)
        a[newPivotPos + 1:], right = QuickSort(B, flag)
        print('A is : ', A)
        print('B is : ', B)
    print('final array: ', a)
    return a,0


a = [35, 50, 15, 25, 80, 20, 90, 45]
# print(QuickSort(a))
```

Output: ([15, 20, 25, 35, 50, 80, 90, 45], 0)

I want to print both number of comparisons and correct quick sort output. For the recursion [90,45] since A = a[0:newPivotPos], 90 is considered pivot, so left array is [] and right array is 45. It gets output as [90,45] rather than [45,90]

Comment: Shouldn't left array be [45]?

Comment: I realised my mistake. j has to go all the way to the last element so changing r= len(a)